# Infinity results

Tags: java, tf-idf

I am trying to calculate the tf and idf of a collection of documents. My problem is that I get infinity and I dont want infinity but I want double results.

Here is my code:

```
 String key = entry.getKey().toString();
 Integer value = entry.getValue().intValue();
 System.out.println("key " + key + " value " + value);

 BigDecimal tf=new BigDecimal(entry.getValue()/collection.size());
 BigDecimal idf=new BigDecimal(Math.log(counter/entry.getValue()));
 BigDecimal tfidf =new BigDecimal((tf.doubleValue())*(idf.doubleValue()));
 System.out.println("TF*IDF: " + key + ": " + tfidf.doubleValue());
```

input:
Map where String is the keyword and the Integer is how many times word appears in the document.

output: 
keyword + TF*IDF:number

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Please give example input, actual output and desired output.

Comment: I think idf will never be 0 because the map always have something

Comment: Most likely either entry.getValue(), collection.size(), or counter have value of 0. That's most likely the cause of you getting infinity. You need to debug to make sure that either it is not acceptable that one of these values would be zero, or add 1 to these values to make sure that you don't get infinities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have a problem in the following line:

```
BigDecimal tf = new BigDecimal(entry.getValue()/collection.size());
```

You're perfroming an integer division. This may be truncated to zero. Try changing this to

```
BigDecimal tf=new BigDecimal((double) entry.getValue()/collection.size());
```

Same problem here:

```
new BigDecimal(Math.log(counter/entry.getValue()));
```

change it to

```
new BigDecimal(Math.log((double) counter/entry.getValue()));
```